# how to analysis this excerpt of Ruby source code about === method

Tags: c, ruby

I found the example and metaphor of `Object#===` operatorare too confusing, I'm now begin to read the source code, But I'm new to C, anyone could tell me how to analysis this code:

```
VALUE
rb_equal(VALUE obj1, VALUE obj2)
{
    VALUE result;

    if (obj1 == obj2) return Qtrue;
    result = rb_funcall(obj1, id_eq, 1, obj2);
    if (RTEST(result)) return Qtrue;
    return Qfalse;
}
```

Comment: can you tell us which part of the code confuses you? if it's the "if (obj1 == obj2) return Qtrue;" it is simply means: "if obj1 is the same as obj2, then this function must return a "true" boolean value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VALUE` is the generic type of Ruby objects in C (as opposed to the C types like `int`). From this you can deduce that `rb_equal` is a function comparing two Ruby objects (`obj1` and `obj2`). If the two objects are equal `Qtrue` (the represantion of Ruby's true in C) will get returned. If not `rb_funcall` will call the equality method (`id_eq`) on `obj1`. If the result is truthy (checked with `RTEST(result)`) `Qtrue` will be returned. If we hit the end of the function the 2 objects are obviously not the same, so we'll return false (`Qfalse`).